$2\times2$ contingency table: z or t test (aka $\chi^2$ or F test)
This question is about good old $2\times2$ contingency tables. One very common test for comparing the proportions in such a table is Pearson's $\chi^2$ test (e.g. here or here). Now, for a $2\times2$ table, this test "degenerates" to a z-test of proportions. Since for a $2\times2$ table, the $\chi^2$ has 1 degree of freedom (d.f), it is just the square of a z statistic. The $\chi^2$ statistic will be exactly the square of the z statistic, the 2 p-values will be exactly the same, etc. So far, so good, this is all well known; I am just setting up the question.
Now, we know that a z test should really only be used when we know the population standard deviation. And when we do not know the population standard deviation, we should instead use a t test. But for our $2\times2$ table case, we do not; we only have an observed estimate. And we even have different estimates of the standard deviation (pooled or unpooled; but let's leave this aside for now).
I have experimented with this, and the results are usually very close between z and t, but I can easily find examples of $2\times2$ tables which are significant for z, but not for t.
So the question is; should we not use a t test instead of the z test, aka, use a F test instead of a $\chi^2$ test? (An F distribution, with 1 d.f. on the numerator, and $n$ d.f. on the denominator is the square of a t distribution with $n$ d.f.). In fact, should we not use a Welch t-test (instead of the z test), to deal with scenarios where the variances may be different?
I have searched the web (and C.V.) but have not found any reference which advocates using a t-test. So is there a theoretical reason why a t test should not be preferentially used over a z test for a $2\times2$ contingency table, or is it just historical legacy?

Can you clarify what you mean by "not valid"? Certainly none of the tests you  mention are exact (none will have the claimed significance level in small samples), but it's possible to justify each of them asymptotically (though in the case of the t, slightly less directly). They should all have the correct significance level in sufficiently large samples and should all have the same asymptotic relative efficiency (of 1, compared to any of the others).

I edited the last paragraph to clarify this. I really meant "why a t-test should not be used preferentially over a z-test" in the case of 2x2 matrices.

I don't follow the premise -- why should it be preferred? Certainly count proportions are not normally distributed so all the tests wouldn't have their underlying assumptions satisfied. The basis of comparison then is how they perform in some set of assumed circumstances (both under H0 and under some set of alternatives). As you point out, there are cases when you reject for Z and not for t (and it's not hard to find some cases that go the other way) so it's not clear to me that there's a current basis to prefer a t-test at all.

As far as I have investigated, they tend to perform well  or not so well in very similar degrees in the same circumstances - so much so that I don't tend to quibble much which someone chooses; the greater issues for me are (a) are we perhaps in a situation where they're both not that great, and (b) will the intended audience accept the use of a t-test without me having to demonstrate that it works essentially as well as the more commonly used z test / chi-squared test. I've seen some econometricians tend to favor teaching the t-test but not much outside that sort of area.

@Glen_b, thanks for the comments. The premise is "under the conditions  where a z-test would be found fit for the task -normal approximation, cells in the 2x2 are all "large enough", etc". Just like one should prefer using a t-test to compare 2 means when the standard deviations are just estimates, should a t-test or proportion not be preferred over a z-test. If both tests are "inadequate", who cares which test one choses; but if z is "adequate", then why not use a t-test? Is there a theoretical reason for not using a t-test, when a z-test is suitable for the job?

@Glen_b, as far as performing similarly in the same circumstances, I would agree with you wrt z-test vs. Student's t-test. But not for z-test vs. Welch t-test; in the case of unequal variances and unbalanced samples (quite common for 2x2 tables), Welch performs much better (alpha error much closer to the nominal). There, one can find many references preferring Welch over Student (e.g. https://daniellakens.blogspot.com/2015/01/always-use-welchs-t-test-instead-of.html#:~:text=Take%20home%20message%20of%20this,sizes%20and%20variances%20are%20equal).  And hence preferring Welch over z.

As far as I can see there's no need to consider the Welch test, since when H0 is true the two population proportions are the same, so the variance is the same when you need it to be; the fact that the variance changes gradually as you move away from the null won't hurt the type I error rate. The problem that the Welch test tries to fix doesn't exist here.

Responding to your earlier comment: you seem to assume that if the z is adequate that the t will be better, but I don't see why you hold that premise.

I hold that premise because the z test assumes the standard deviation is known, which it is not.  One does not compare means with a z test (one used to...). The z-test underestimates the CI of the difference of means, hence overestimates the effect, underestimates the p-value, etc.

Thanks, I think I now see where some of your mistaken premises arise. I'll see if I can write some suitable discussion.

@Glen_b, thanks. I look forward to it. As you know, in the 2x2 case, comparing proportions using a normal approximation is exactly a comparison of means (comparing the means of 2 indicator variables). One does preferentially use a t-test for that, and not a z-test, hence my wondering why a z/$chi^2$ test is used, instead of a t/F, and hence my question.

The use of chi-square tests for this sort of thing is justified by a theorem saying that that is the approximate null distribution of the test statistic when the sample size is big enough. When the sample size is small, the use of the t-distribution is indicated when sampling from a normally distributed population. But this is certainly not a normally distributed population. Note my use of the word "approximately". There are also "exact" tests, and those don't involve the t-distribution as the null distribution of a test statistic.

You seem to be relying on an ad hoc argument that if the standard deviation of some population distribution is unknown, then if we have a statistic of the form:
$$\frac{\langle\text{estimate of mean}\rangle - \langle\text{population mean}\rangle}{(\langle\text{estimate of standard deviation} \rangle / \sqrt{n})}$$
that you will necessarily get significance levels (and hence p-values) nearer to what they should be from using an ordinary one sample t test
than from using the usual asymptotic test based on the normal. The argument seems to be based on an unstated underlying idea that the "t" (or something very close to it) arises
whenever the standard deviation is estimated rather than known.
I have seen some books (including but not limited to non-mathematical books for introductory statistics) make such arguments, so it's not surprising you might think this to be the case. We must beware taking such hand-waving as a fact rather than somewhat loose motivation.
To clarify the circumstances, what leads a t-statistic to have a t-distribution relies on properties of the normal distribution. The CLT doesn't give us that the t-statistic has a t-distribution. Instead we rely on three things: the normality of the sample mean, the fact that $(n-1)s^2/\sigma^2$ is distributed as a $\chi^2_{n-1}$, and the fact that $\bar{x}$ and $s$ are independent. These all happen when sampling independently from a population process that is normal. When it isn't normal, you don't get a t-distribution.
[In what follows, imagine we are testing a hypothesis that a set of 0/1 values is i.i.d. Bernoulli($p_0$) for some hypothesized population proportion $p_0$. Let $\bar{x}=p$ be the sample average of the binary values.]
Note in particular that in the case of the proportions test, $\bar{x}$ and $s$ are perfectly dependent and $(n-1)s^2/\sigma^2$ is not distributed as $\chi^2$, so the statistic doesn't have a t-distribution.
We can make arguments that both the usual z-statistic $\frac{\bar{x}-p_0}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}}$ and the t-statistic based on the sample of 0/1 values will be asymptotically normal (given a few basic conditions) and because the t will also approach the normal in the limit as $n$ goes to infinity, when the conditions for the normal to be a good approximation  in large samples hold, the t should provide a good approximation as well. This argument, gives no guarantees that the t-test is better than the more commonly used z test at small sample sizes.
Indeed to my knowledge we don't presently have a theorem that establishes that t will do better than z in general circumstances, outside the case of a normal population process. Though often in practice it will be the case that it does a little better, it does not occur universally and indeed in the case of a one-sample proportions test, sometimes it isn't the case.
I did see some papers around a decade ago that did seem to suggest we (the collective we of the enterprise of statistics) might perhaps be getting close to some kind of characterization of when the t actually does give a better approximation than the z, but I haven't seen anything yet that indicates that this occurred.
Is there a problem with using the t-test for a proportions test? No, it performs quite well, very similar to the z test. Further, given it very often does slightly better than the z (e.g. in terms of adherence to significance level), perhaps there's a reasonable argument for using it more.  So while I believe your underlying reasoning is flawed, I would agree with the conclusion that - if your only options are one or the other of those two tests - then there's a reason to slightly prefer the t.
However, we should not fool ourselves that we have solved a problem:
(i) sometimes both tests are poor approximations, and
(ii) we aren't limited to just using one or the other.

Thanks for taking the time to answer, and thanks for the considerate answer. Is there a way we could continue this conversation, but not via comments? E.g. I ran some quick simulations, and it gave me some unexpected (to me) results (e.g. that $(n−1)s^2/σ^2$ does follow close enough to a $\chi^2$ distribution when $p_0=.1$, but not at all when $p_0=.5$ -negatively skewed distribution in that case)). I also have follow up comments/questions. Thanks in advance

You're welcome to ping me on Ten Fold, though if it's a lot we'll need to move it. When you say "close enough", it depends on your sample size and what you regard as "close"; note that for the tails of the t, the left tail of $s^2$ matters. I had originally intended to write a slightly different answer but I was unwell for about a week and only able to focus for a few minutes at a time (longer than needed to do this justice). Unfortunately I no longer remember enough of the details of what I had planned, only something of the gist of it. * This is not the greatest song in the world...*

Alternatively if it's a lot you can post a new question and link to this one, so you're not just relying on me. On the internet nobody knows you're just a dog.
